# Overridden Jasmine spy in mock not compiling in TypeScript properly

Tags: javascript, typescript, mocking, jasmine2.0

I'm trying to override/re=assign a Jasmine spy on a mock and can't seem to get it to work. The mock looks like this:

```
export class UserClassMock {
    public static instance(): any {
        let instance = jasmine.createSpyObj('userClass', [
            'id',
            'isLoggedIn',
            'message',
            'firstName',
            'lastName',
            'emailAddress',
            'username',
            'password',
            'save',
            'load',
            'remove',
            'login',
            'signUp',
            'resetPassword'
        ]);

        instance.id.and.returnValue(0);
        instance.isLoggedIn.and.returnValue(true);
        instance.message.and.returnValue('');
        instance.firstName.and.returnValue('');
        instance.lastName.and.returnValue('');
        instance.emailAddress.and.returnValue('');
        instance.username.and.returnValue('');
        instance.password.and.returnValue('');
        instance.save.and.returnValue(Promise.resolve());
        instance.load.and.returnValue(Promise.resolve());
        instance.remove.and.returnValue(Promise.resolve());
        instance.login.and.returnValue(Promise.resolve());
        instance.signUp.and.returnValue(Promise.resolve());
        instance.resetPassword.and.returnValue(Promise.resolve());

        return instance;
    }
}
```

The test suite is set up like this:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    navCtrl = NavControllerMock.instance();
    formBuilder = FormBuilderMock.instance();
    alertController = AlertControllerMock.instance();
    userClass = UserClassMock.instance();
    loggingService = LoggingServiceMock.instance();

    loginComponent = new LoginComponent(navCtrl, formBuilder, userClass, loggingService, alertController);
});
```

I am trying to override the spy like this:

```
it('should try to raise an alert when the login fails', () => {
    userClass.login = jasmine.createSpy('login', () => {}).and.returnValue(Promise.reject());
    loginComponent.attemptLogin();
    expect(alertController.create).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

When I run the test in question I get this error:

```
webpack: Compiling...
>> ERROR in ./src/app/login/login.component.spec.ts
>> (112,76): error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

My first thought was to include two parameters in the mock like so:

```
userClass.login = jasmine.createSpy('login', (key, value) => {}).and.returnValue(Promise.reject());
```

This did not solve the problem. What I don't understand is why this method of overriding a spy from a mock works in other places where the method being mocked has parameters, but in this method it is having a fit about it? I have another test with the same issue, but it uses the StorageMock from [Ionic-Mocks](https://github.com/stonelasley/ionic-mocks) and I still get the same result when I try to override the spy for either method. Any insight into why this is happening and how to correct it is appreciated.

Comment: Does `createSpy` take a second argument, according to the typing?

Comment: Ya know, that's a good question. I looked at the docs (https://jasmine.github.io/api/2.7/jasmine.html) and found that it says that the second argument should be what will take the place of the original function. Let me try some variants on that that and see what comes. Thanks!

Comment: I tried several different permutations, but still no luck.